# adding a quiz to app with sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to learn how to make a quiz to add to my app. I have done extensive searches and found that I will be using SQlite. Which I have seen how a database gets created from a couple of sites. But I was wondering if there was a better tutorial to this. I know that Appinventer has a quiz tutorial but putting blocks together does not show me the code snippets that I am using and therefor in the end I end up learning nothing but putting blocks together. 
Anyone have a tutorial on how to do a quiz basic question and answer and give a score at the end?

Or is there a way to see the underlying code to a project we build with appinventor?

after doing research I decided to go for basics as I get more skills. Here is what my research has yeilded so far. Am I going in the right direction?

```
   int i = 0;
TextView tv; 
 String[] Food = {"Ice Cream", "Bacon", "Cheese", "Sandwich"};

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arraylay);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

            Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (i < Food.length){                          
            tv.setText(Food[i]);
            i++;
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didn't think I was asking for the whole source code.  I am asking for a tutorial if someone has one. Or is there a way to open up appinventor the google appbuilder suite and look under the blocks to see the code that I am building as I drop blocks into place.

Comment: I take back my comment then. "Anyone have a tutorial on how to do a quiz basic question and answer and give a score at the end" this line jumped at me. It did sound like you are asking for a tutorial for making X app. :) Generally these questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: Looking back it does sound like I was asking for code rather than a tutorial maybe I should have phrased it. As for tutorial I wanted something that went along the lines as Do research on A and do this tutorial which will help you. Do research on B and do this other tutorial from google. Then put them together and you will have a base to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/userfaq.html). Sadly no it does not generate source code.

*(also real developers dont use app inventor)*

Comment: Reno Thank you. That answers part of what I am looking for.

Comment: @Reno I am taking a step back from sqlite and trying with an array. I did some research and then came up with something like the code I just added. Can you or anyone tell me if it is in the right direction?

Comment: @Reno as for the real developers dont use app inventor I agree. But as I was getting desperate to find a tutorial to help me. Though I must say as I did searches on the web Iphone has many quiz tutorials in detail so I now I am left thinking that A) making a quiz on android is uber hard and people gaurd their hard work like fort knox. Or B) It is so basic that finishing tutorials from google and someone should be able to make it in their sleep.  Either way I am working on it.

Comment: @BluMouse 1) That code wont compile. 2) You dont need an HashMap and ArrayList<String> will do. 3) Keeping two like HashMap AND and an array (food) is redundant. 4) Icecream is never added to the list ? maybe this is by design. But you can modify your code so that you dont have two count++ ... think about it.  Developing an quiz like app is easy IMO but yeah you have to learn some stuff on android and java programming.

Comment: @Reno Thanks for the fast reply. I will look into Arraylist<String> and learn some more.

Comment: @Reno  Thankyou for your help. I have learned a lot since you put the numbers as to helping me. I am still looking into arraylist<String> but I wanted to try it with a simple String Array and found it worked. I am so happy because this took me a long way and my research paid off. Thank you again.